# The full symmetry group and infinitesimal generators of the quantum Hall effect

Tags: symmetry, quantum-hall-effect

What is the full symmetry group and infinitesimal generators of the quantum Hall effect (in the continuum, not a lattice)? For example the kelper potential has $SO(4)$ symmetry with the angular momentum and Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector giving the infinitesimal generators (in the operator representation) $\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ which each generate $SU(2)$ and we see $SU(2)\times SU(2)\sim SO(4)$. But what are these quantities for the QHE? Specifically the full symmetry group of the QHE (I'm working in the symmetric gauge if that matters) and what are the infinitesimal generator operators of this symmetry? Would the exponent of the magnetic translation operator be an infinitesimal generator for the Galilean translation part of the symmetry?